# Column index not working on columns with date and time values in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that fetches column index numbers from column values. It is working perfectly fine for the column values that are text but the values that are date and time, it doesn't even recognize them. don't know why. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the code.

```
function columnindex(){
  const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname");
  selected_columns = ["Keywords", "Wed Feb 02 2022 05:55:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"].toString()

  var columns = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues().toString();
  Logger.log(columns)
  for (i = 0; i < selected_columns.length; i++) {
    let column = columns[0].indexOf(selected_columns[i]);
    if (column != -1) {
      Logger.log(column+1)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried it with and without string property but it doesn't seem working.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample sheet for replicating your issue as the image? By this, I would like to confirm the values of your header row.

Comment: Sure [here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zg8nd81POEU0MTikLg1E02gZkj7I8UJigPwZQ4Xw7Tw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: oh Ok.. thank you for the guidance. I will just delete the sheet once you have seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified script? I thought that in your situation, `getDisplayValues()` might be suitable.

#### Modified script:

```js
function columnindex() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  selected_columns = ["Keywords", "2/2/2022"];
  var columns = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  var columnIndexes = selected_columns.map(e => columns.indexOf(e));
  console.log(columnIndexes);
}
```

- From `I have a script that fetches column index numbers from column values.` in your question, in this modification, `columnIndexes` returns the column indexes that the 1st number is `0`. If you want to the coulmn number, please modify `var columnIndexes = selected_columns.map(e => columns.indexOf(e));` to `var columnIndexes = selected_columns.map(e => columns.indexOf(e) + 1);`.

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)